# How to read a file that contains both ANSI and UTF-8 encoded characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, ansi

I get a file from a third party. The file seems to contain both ANSI and UTF-8 encoded characters (not sure if my terminology is correct).

Changing the encoding in Notepad++ yields the following:

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

So when using ANSI encoding, Employee2 is incorrect. And when using UTF-8 encoding, Employee1 is incorrect.

Is there a way in C# to set 2 encodings for a file?

Whichever encoding I set in C#, one of the two employees is incorrect:

```
string filetext = "";

// Employee1 is correct, Employee2 is wrong
filetext = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TESTFILE.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));   
filetext = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TESTFILE.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")); 
filetext = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TESTFILE.txt", Encoding.UTF7);                        
filetext = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TESTFILE.txt", Encoding.Default);                     

// Employee1 is wrong, Employee2 is correct
filetext = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TESTFILE.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Perhaps you need another character set? There are many more possible encodings. You could use `Encoding.GetEncodings` to just try every possible encoding.

Comment: Since a text format is just a bunch of bytes (the BOM or Byte Order Mark appart but it's always at the very beginning of the file), technically, there's nothing that prevents a file from containing various texts using various encodings, but that's very weird and instead looks like a bug (especially if there's nothing in front of this text or somewhere that indicates the encoding).

Comment: If this is a file provided by an external party, ask them to specify the encoding they are using. There's no point in trying to work around such issues.
If the file is created by a download process under your control it's a different story and you will need to look into that operation.

Comment: @JonasH Thank you, `Encoding.GetEncodings()` returns 140 encodings. I looped and read the file with all of them but none of the returned text contained both É and Ò

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that one of these was originally created with an incorrect encoding in the first place, so the problem is at the source.

Comment: It’s no guess. The problem is at the source.